# Babel 6 - Enable default parameters for functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a piece of code:

```
'use strict';

class ArticleModel {

  constructor(options = {}) {
    this.options = options
  }

}

module.exports = ArticleModel
```

which results in the error `Unexpected token =` - I don't believe Babel is parsing this. Which babel 6 plugin is needed to parse default parameters in a function?

Edit 1 - this is my .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

Edit 2 - I am not running babel from the same directory as `.babelrc`. I'm running babel from inside `test/` where the structure looks like this:

```
/app
/test
/test/runner.js < -- this is what calls babel-core/register
.babelrc
```

Do I need to explicitly tell `babel-core/register` where `.babelrc` is? I assumed it rolled up a directory for it.

Edit 3 - changed `babel/register` to `babel-core/register`. Still get the same issue.

Comment: 'babel/register' doesn't exist anymore? should be 'babel-core/register'

Comment: Tks @Seneca but I still get the same error even when changing it to `babel-core/register`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you importing the module into the test? I had a similar problem when my tests started to break after upgrading from Babel 5 to 6. In my case it turned out that the problem was because the import has to referenced the `default` property in the imported lib.

The initiator of this Babel issue gives a good example: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2679

Comment: Why did this change? Do you know?

Comment: Yes, Babel5 allowed you to use incorrect ES6 syntax. Babel6 "fixes" this to force the correct syntax. It's fairly confusing and I think that a lot of people will be impacted by this.

Answer (score 5):

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Add the following line to your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"] 
}
```

Did you try this?

Comment: yes I did. I added my `.babelrc` file in the question.

Comment: Why did Babel do this? so annoying.

Comment: @ChrisAbrams I know I'm a bit late in the party. But did you try installing it `npm i -D babel-preset-es2015`?